# In Silverlight: How to Populate Silverlight Datagrid to Silverlight Controls Programmatically?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

hi Friends
          I'm working on silverlight 4.0, I have datagrid the data are loaded from database 
          My Question is the when the user click's the record in datagrid. The records automatically populated in silverlight controls

Example
       in the datagrid i have empid and empname when user click the empid or empname the data to loaded in empid(textbox) and empname(textbox).

Can any one please Post the code......

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, yo have something like "master/detail", AKA you click on a datagrid row and you want a couple of textboxes filled.

So, when you click on a row, launch the SelectionChanged event, get the element attached to that row (the Employee) and assign it to a "SelectedEmployee" property. The textboxes' datacontext is that SelectedEmployee. Bind every textbox to a SelectedEmployee property (empid, empname...)

Is that what you want? :)

Here is the example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">

    </sdk:DataGrid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedEmployee.Id}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedEmployee.EmpName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I have a DataGrid (the name is because Im using codebehind in this example). A Datagrid with data and two textboxes that will contain the data of the selected row on the datagrid.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee {Id = 1, EmpName = "Raj"});
        employees.Add(new Employee {Id = 2, EmpName = "Jesus"});
        datagrid.ItemsSource = Employees;

        Page.DataContext = this;
    }

    private Employee _selectedEmployee;


    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return employees; }
    }

    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        }
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedEmployee = datagrid.SelectedItem as Employee;
    }
```

Again the codebehind shit, but the idea is that. You have a ItemsSource binded to your DataGrid and you have a SelectedEmployee property.

So, when I click on a row, the SelectedChanged event will be launched and you have to get the Employee asigned to that row, putting it to the SelectedEmployee property and because the textboxes are assigned to that property, you will see them filled.

Better now? :)

Comment: Its easy, try it yourself or I will update this with an example later (I have to go right now, sorry)